# Blacklisting Network Range on django-blacklist

Tags: django, network-programming, ip

I've noticed recently that my django-website is being crawled by a number of spammy bots, so while looking for a way to block this IP-range I came across django-blacklist. It works well for the most part, and I've successfully blocked single IPs, but when I tried to block a range (51.222.253.0 - 51.222.253.255), it seems to be unsuccessful. My inputs were: Address = 51.222.253.0 & Prefixlen = 24 (see image below).

I've read the docs, and can't seem to get more clarity on this topic, however, this isn't a strong suit of mine so let me know if I've done something wrong. All help is appreciated!

[image: django-blacklist screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure this is not IPv6?

Comment: django-blacklist takes either IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: yes but the checks are not compatible: it stores the ranges in a dictionary, and `123.45,67.0/24` is not equivalent to `::123.45.67.0/120`.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not very well versed in this topic. Are you suggesting that perhaps the IP above is IPv6 (not IPv4), and therefore the value I have for the prefix length could be wrong?